# Combining different shell commands in a script

Tags: bash

I am trying to accomplish a series of 4 steps in extracting and moving the files using bash script

```
  1. Cd to a folder "/folder/test1"
  2. Run a shell script to get the variable "$hours"
  3. Cd to a folder "/folder/test2"
  4. Use the variable "$hours" created in step 2 to run the below command:
           grep -h projname $(find check** -maxdepth 1 -mtime $hours) > folder/extraction_08_03_2021.txt
```

Currently, I manually cd to the folder and run the script/commands separately. I am new to shell scripting, not sure whether the 4 steps could be combined in a shell script so that I just run the .sh script and this gets executed automatically.

Any suggestions/leads would be appreciated.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't run a separate shell script to get the $hours variable. That would be tricky as shell scripts cannot return bash variables, so you'd need to have that script write $hours to a temporary file or something.

Comment: Just add the command run in each to a file and add #!/bin/bash to formulate a script?

Comment: Most probably the command substitution can go. Just use the good ol pipe line. `find .... | grep .... > file`

Comment: Before running your script, I recommend running it past [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net); it's good at pointing out common scripting mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead off `cd`'ing back and forward, set the `find`/shell command to the desired folder

   ```
   find /folder/test1/check** ...
   ```
2. Call *the shell script* using [bash command substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118433/quoting-within-command-substitution-in-bash)

   ```
   find ... -mtime $(myShellScriptThatReturnsHours)
   ```
3. Instead of `cd`'ing back, use `../` to get the [parent dir](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397524/what-does-the-mean-dot-slash-in-linux)
4. Using the above points, you can use something like

   ```
   grep -h projname $(find /folder/test1/check** -maxdepth 1 -mtime "$(myShellScriptThatReturnsHours)) > folder/extraction_08_03_2021.txt
   ```

   **Note**:

   If `../` is not enough to 'change' dirs, you can call `myShellScriptThatReturnsHours` in a [sub-shell we're you navigate to the desired folder](https://superuser.com/questions/271986/execute-a-command-from-another-directory-in-bash).

   ```
   -mtime $(( cd /folder/test1/; myShellScriptThatReturnsHours))
   ```